# Counting non blank cell results without looping in Excel VBA -- e.g., with Specialcells

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

Here is the code I'm trying to count with in VBA, hoping to return 
a count return variable of "3" from 'FormulaResultCount'. Why can't I
count what is visibly returned by the formulas within each cell; from the grey box (see photo below)?

```
 Sub countNonBlanks()

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("C:C").Select


        FormulaResultCount = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Count


            'SpecialCells options from MSFT            
            '        xlCellTypeAllFormatConditions. Cells of any format -4172
            '        xlCellTypeAllValidation. Cells having validation criteria -4174
            '        xlCellTypeBlanks. Empty cells 4
            '        xlCellTypeComments. Cells containing notes -4144
            '        xlCellTypeConstants. Cells containing constants 2
            '        xlCellTypeFormulas. Cells containing formulas -4123
            '        xlCellTypeLastCell. The last cell in the used range 11
            '        xlCellTypeSameFormatConditions. Cells having the same format -4173
            '        xlCellTypeSameValidation. Cells having the same validation -4175
            '        xlCellTypeVisible. All visible cells
            '

    End Sub
```

See formula as reference:

[image]

Note: Since I will have many more cells when working dynamically, loops will likely slow the process down too much. Also, I tried using CountA without result.

Comment: What value gets assigned to `FormulaResultCount`?

Comment: if D is showing the formula you have in C, I'd expect your answer to be 5.  They are still formulas even if they result in "" as an answer.

Comment: @DougGlancy A value of 5 gets assigned, counting each cell with a formula. Instead I would like to be assigned a 3 for the cells triggered by column B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> xlCellTypeFormulas. Cells containing formulas -4123

This would not return the cell based on their values but if they have any formula or not. As per your worksheet, you should get `5`

Also, PLEASE PLEASE do not use `.Select` [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Your code can also be written as

`FormulaResultCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Count`

**Another Tip**: When using `SpecialCells`, use appropriate error handling so that if there are no cells which match the `SpecialCells` criteria, your code won't break. See this example.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Rng = .Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        If Err <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "No Cells with formulas were found"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    FormulaResultCount = Rng.Count

    Debug.Print FormulaResultCount
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP From Comments**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Debug.Print Evaluate("=COUNTA(C1:C" & lRow & _
                    ")-COUNTIF(C1:C" & lRow & ","""")")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Very interesting approach, but it still returns a 5, when I'm looking to return a 3 -- i.e., for each value returned by if() functions. Is there an alt to 'xlCellTypeFormulas' in the list above which might work with the code you shared?

Comment: @BobHopez: I have updated the post. See `FOLLOWUP From Comments`

Comment: Good attempt; still returns a 5. Want to just search column C--not sure why the FOLLOWUP uses "A"--regardless, "A"/"C" in place still returns 5 and not 3.

Comment: Scratch that @SiddharthRout!! I checked the immediate window, and the three popped up...many of them.

Comment: Note to readers: `Application.SendKeys "^g ^a {DEL}"` clears the immediate window.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this:

```
FormulaResultCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C:C"), "?*")
```

Thus counting all cells in range that start with any character?

Answer (score 3):

What you really might want is:

```
FormulaResultCount = Evaluate("CountA(C:C)")
```

I just learnt about the evaluate command.  It's awesome!

And it gives you 3 :)

Comment: @Derek Might be a good alternative, but it still returns a 5, as there are 5 functions in the C column. I would like to return a 3, for each value triggered as visible from the  if() within the cells.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without VBA, using only formulas.

```
=ROWS(range)*COLUMNS(range)-COUNTBLANK(range)
```

If you're trying to do this in VBA, you can use this:

```
Function non_blank_cell_results_count(r As Range) As Long
  non_blank_cell_results_count = r.Cells.Count - WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(r)
End Function
```